# What is this G button function in blender called(happens in Edit mode)?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGVMXyZNCQY
[image]

My shadowplay is acting up so its low rez for some reason(i set it as 720p)...

Basically if you recreate the rentancle(i had to do it for my project model i am working on) and press G button multiple times in edit mode(but in order for this to work you have to select same edges i had).

What is this blender function called? Is it similar to google sketchup follow me function?

If your edges turn yellowish, this is the function i got/found and i cant find any info on it....

Comment: I think you are referring to the "edge slide" function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Edge Slide function. Selecting an edge and pressing G two times will enable this. It allows you to manipulate edges along other edges, scaling then accordingly to maintain the overall shape while moving the edge. An example can be seen below on my mesh:

[image]

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
On your video, in the bottom left corner, you can see you have "Vert Slide" enabled. This works similar to Edge Slide.
[image]

Comment: in your gif above it's not that clear which key you are pressing to change the edge edit behaviour...

Comment: I'm aware of that, but unsure how to pop up the box that shows what key you press. I've heard about it, but never used it as I don't record tutorials and such.. If you know how to enable that, I'll edit my GIF. Although I did mention "Selecting an edge and pressing G two times will enable this.", but I understand that can be vague.

Comment: I think this might be it, if you select two more edges, will those 2 more edges turn yellowish? If they do then this is the answer i am looking for!

Comment: Updated my answer with a better GIF. This do indeed demonstrate what you described